# How to modify this code to use good practices? (interface, trait, abstract class)

Tags: php

I decided to learn PHP, watched a few basic tutorials, and made a simple script to try the basics. The script works, but is probably not written using good practices.

Should I use static/private/protected variables/functions somewhere?

Should I move variables from Trait somewhere else?

Should I implement Interface on each class separately (VideoOrganizer, ImageOrganizer) instead of using abstract class with Interface?

Or something else that could be done better?

Thanks

```
<?php

interface OrganizerInterface
{
    public function organize($folder);
}


trait OrgnaizeTrait
{
    public $filesInDir = "";
    public $destinationFolder;
    public $formats;

    public function organize($folder)
    {
        echo "Destination folder: " . $this->destinationFolder . "\n";
        print_r($this->formats);
        echo "Moving files from folder: " . $folder . "\n";
    }
}


abstract class Organizer implements OrganizerInterface
{
    use OrgnaizeTrait;
}


class VideoOrganizer extends Organizer 
{
    public $destinationFolder = '/videos';
    public $formats = ['.avi', '.mov'];
}


class ImageOrganizer extends Organizer
{
    public $destinationFolder = '/images';
    public $formats = ['.jpg', '.png'];
}


class Application
{
    public $organizer;
    public function __construct(OrganizerInterface $organizer)
    {
        $this->organizer = $organizer;
    }
}

$app = new Application(new VideoOrganizer());
$app->organizer->organize("/home/Tomas");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit too much of an open-ended question for SO (and it would probably fit https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ a bit better), but here are a few points:

- public properties are bad and you should avoid them most of, if not all the time,
- I don't see the point of using a trait (they're often a sign of bad design, and they don't appear to serve much purpose in your case),
- `OrgnaizeTrait` has a typo :)
- what's the point of `$filesInDir` if it's not used at all? (I realize your code is partly pseudo-code, but still),
- it's very hard to give you a good answer without knowing what you're attempting to do exactly, and what the purposes of these classes are.

Here's a possible "cleaner" version of your code:

```
interface OrganizerInterface
{
    public function organize(string $folder);
}

final class BasicOrganizer implements OrganizerInterface
{
    private string $destinationFolder;
    /** @var string[] */
    private array $formats;

    /**
     * @param string[] $formats
     */
    public function __construct(string $destinationFolder, array $formats)
    {
        $this->destinationFolder = $destinationFolder;
        $this->formats = $formats;
    }

    public function organize(string $folder): void
    {
        echo "Destination folder: {$this->destinationFolder}\n";
        print_r($this->formats);
        echo "Moving files from folder: {$folder}\n";
    }
}

final class Application
{
    private OrganizerInterface $organizer;

    public function __construct(OrganizerInterface $organizer)
    {
        $this->organizer = $organizer;
    }

    public function doStuffThatNeedsAnOrganizer(string $folder): void
    {
        // Do stuff here if needed

        $this->organizer->organize($folder);

        // Do more stuff here if needed
    }
}

$videosOrganizer = new BasicOrganizer('/videos', ['.avi', '.mov']);
$imagesOrganizer = new BasicOrganizer('/images', ['.jpg', '.mov']);

$app = new Application($imagesOrganizer);
$app->doStuffThatNeedsAnOrganizer('/home/Tomas');
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. `$filesInDir` will be used in the function organize(). The purpose of this script is to organize files. For example, move files in the Downloads folder by extension to /music, /documents etc. :)I wanted to make the script so that it could be easily expanded in the future, for example a new organizer that moves files to folders according to some regex (and not just according to extensions, as in the example).

Comment: @b0z1k You can easily add `$filesInDir` to `BasicOrganizer`'s properties if needed. As for other types of organizes, you'd just implement the interface again with, say, `DynamicOrganizer` or something, which would have a regex as one of its properties.